# Inserting multiple buttons onto a page in one line

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to insert a few buttons onto a page using a Chrome Extension. I don't own the page and can't control the CSS.

I want them all in one line. Right now they are all appearing on their own line and taking up the entire width.

```
var inMailButton = $('<button  type="button">Add to Response</button>')
var notInterested = $('<button class="column" type=button>Not Interested</button>')
var noRelo = $('<button class="column" type=button">No Relo</button>')
var interested = $('<button class="column" type=button">Interested</button>')

var responseLocation = $('#mailbox-main')

responseLocation.prepend(notInterested)
responseLocation.prepend(noRelo)
responseLocation.prepend(interested)
responseLocation.prepend(inMailButton)
```

This appears on the page like:

```
Add To Response
Not Interested
No Relo
Interested
```

Whereas I want them to be side by side

```
Add to Response | Not Interested | No Relo | Interested
```

I was trying to add them to a `<span>` first, and then add that to `responseLocation` but I can't get it working as I wanted.

How would I do this?

Comment: Buttons, on their own, shouldn't go to new lines.  What CSS do you have that is making this happen?

Comment: This is the default behaviour as buttons are set to `display: inline-block` by default: https://jsfiddle.net/v4muncsp/. If this isn't happening it's down to your own CSS. You need to amend it

Answer (score 1):

Add to your CSS:

```
#mailbox-main button {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do this a few ways...

the inline-block way:

```
button {
    display: inline-block
}
```

Or use flex box, but that would require a housing div like so...

```
<div class="buttonContainer">
    <button>button 1</button>
    <button>button 2</button>
    <button>button 3</button>
</div>

//CSS
.buttonContainer {
   display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding display flex to your responseLocation

```
#mailbox-main{
display:flex;
}
```